# Spring JDBCTemplate to retrieve collection of objects each of which also has its own collection

Tags: collections, jdbctemplate

I know how to process and return a collection of objects with Spring JdbcTemplate using the methods in that class. My issue is with objects in  my collection also having their own collection. As such, my regular RowMapper approach isn’t cutting it.

Environment: Java 8, Spring 4.x, Tomcat, Oracle.

I have:

```
Public class Human{
String name;
Long id
List<Child> children;
}

Public Class Child{
String name;
int age;
long id
}
```

I want to return
List humans  such that

```
List index    --- ---------- contents
0--> Hunan1 {child1, child2, child3}  -- has three three
1--> Human2 {} – has no child
2--> Human3{childx, childy} – has 2 children
```

My Oracle tables are  like this:

```
Human
Id  Name    address
1   James   123 Main street
2   Bob 246 Broad street
3   Tiger   850 First street

Child
Id  Name    age
5   Dave    10
7   Lille   15


Human_Child
HumanId ChildId xzy
1   5   
1   7   
2   5   
3   0


SQL
SELECT  hm.id, hm.name, ch.id, chi.name
FROM HUMAN hm
left outer JOIN HUMAN_CHILDREN hm_ch ON hm_ch.id = hm.id
left outer JOIN CHILD ch ON ch.id = hm_ch.id

ResultSet
humanId HumanName   ChildId ChildName
1   James   5   Dave
1   James   7   Lille
2   Bob 5   Dave
3   Tiger   Null    null
```

I want James to be one object in my list but James should have a list itself holding his two children as described earlier. I guess I could return a list with duplicate humans and instead use a map to create the children list but that would be too many loops -  I just want to do it all at once in my DAO layer while processing the resulset. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in your `RowMapper` for `Human`. What you will have to do is load the ids of the `Children` on `Human` and then write a separate method that does a separate db call to retrieve `Children` with those ids and load them onto `Human`.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed. Would it be a better approach to make two DB calls (one for humans, another for children) as opposed to loading all at once(both humnan and children) and finding the child collections on the Java side?

Comment: @mgibson not sure how you would do it one db call, you will most likely have to do two. One to load the humans, and then another to retrieve the relevant children. If resource contention is an issue you want to consider using the `@Transactional` annotation on the method you're calling from. This ensures a single connection is used for all database transactions.